# Indexing Service: getting empty columns on custom properties

Tags: c#, indexing-service

I'm following this example:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/getting-started-with-indexing-service.html

However, the conversion to dataset shows empty columns for my custom properties.  If I use path or filename for the columns I get data back.  I have set the properties to be cached, have tried both levels, and have rescanned full.

I've tried this example on my desktop (windows vista 32bit) and on a Windows 2008 R2 server with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the gridview's autogenerate columns was not working on this datatable that was generated.  If I specify the columns in the gridview then, I get data back.

I've never seen this before, especially with what appears to be a well formed datatable (ie columns are all specified).